# setBackgroundResources in ImageButton doesn't work

Tags: android, expandablelistview, imagebutton

I have `ImageButton` in row on `ExpandableListView`. I added on click handler to this button.

```
public void expandCollapse(View v){
    int position = Integer.parseInt((String)v.getTag());

    if(mList.isGroupExpanded(position)){
        mList.collapseGroup(position);
        v.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.collapse);

    }else{
        mList.expandGroup(position);
        v.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.expand);
    }
}
```

I have images in resources and collapsing/expanding works fine
but image dosen't change.
Does somebody know solution?

Answer (score 0):

For ImageButton use [setImageResource(int resId)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.html#setImageResource(int))

Answer (score 0):

Try setImageResource or setImageDrawable